# NodeList length is always 0

Tags: javascript, xml

Trying to read the XML file in a tpl file (Smarty Template) like this:

```
<script>
                       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                   xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/testXML.xml", false);
                   xmlhttp.send();
                   //xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseText;
                   xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseXML, "text/xml");
                   alert(xmlDoc);
                   document.write("<table border='1'>");
                   //var x = new object();
                   var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                   alert(x);
                   //alert(x.length);
                   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
                   {
                         document.write("<tr><td>");
                         document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                         alert(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].nodeValue);
                         document.write("</td><td>");
                         document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Location")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                         document.write("</td></tr>");
                   }
                   document.write("</table>");

 </script>
```

alert(x.length) always returns 0. This looks like a pretty standard code that I found and assembled from the net.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: What happens if you open http://localhost:8080/testXML.xml in your browser? When you open the page in chrome and press F12 you can inspect the xmlhttprequest in the network tab (or console) what does that show you? These things have been suggested before but not sure what the outcome was

Answer (score 3):

First, I would confirm that `xmlhttp.responseXML` actually contains data. Monitor your network panel (if you're using a browser) for the server response.

Second, if your `xmlhttp.responseXML` is `null` but your `xmlhttp.responseText` is not, it indicates there is an issue with the XML document -- typically malformed tags/schema, or leading white-space. From what you have posted, I don't see any issues (and `DOMParser()` grokked the XML just fine.)

Last, there should be no need to use `DOMParser()`, since `xmlhttp.responseXML` **is** an XML document (assuming it has been parsed correctly after loading).

[EDIT]

Also note that if the page is not also being loaded from `localhost:8080`, you may not be getting back any data, due to cross-domain restrictions inherent in AJAX.

Comment: Cross-domain issues would present themselves as errors. Good point though :)

Comment: I had to use DOMParser because xmlhttp.responseXML was showing null. Even now my resposeXML is showing null, while responseText is blank. What should I do?

Comment: What does your developer console show? What is the response from the server?

Comment: @Phil, true enough. I sort of never trust all browsers to do the same thing, but that is in the AJAX spec.

Comment: If I use DOMParser().FormatString xmlDoc is object Document, else its null.

Comment: So try dropping `DOMParser()` and work on the XML document directly. That method is normally used only for deserializing an XML string (that is, a string that consists of valid XML). What your code is doing is attempting to `parseFromString()` something that isn't a string in order to produce an XML document. Just use the XML document you got from the AJAX response.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to parse your `responseXML` it is an actual XML Document object by itself if the response content type header is set correctly.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLqX2/)

```
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
alert(x.length);
```

Comment: What is this in the fiddle: xmlhttp.send('xml=' + encodeURIComponent(xml)); ?? Do I need to change it in my code?

Comment: No. That is to simulate the AJAX request on JSFiddle. Just ensure that the `Content-Type` header is set to `text/xml` from your server response

Comment: And how exactly do I do that?

Comment: That depends on which server-side programming language/framework you are using

Comment: In his comments to the other answer, he says `responseText` is blank, so it's not likely a `Content-Type` issue. My bet is either the response is blocked or the server is not responding with the expected data from his actual request.

Comment: So responseXML is null, responseText is blank, and I dont know how to set the Content-Type header. Any suggestions?